# How to use refs over an HOC in react?

Tags: reactjs, ref, higher-order-components

I've a Component (Wrapped with HOC) which is being mounted in my app at several places. I've to add some custom events such as `drag`, `dragLeave` etc. using `node.addEventListener` in `ComponentDidMount` and need to remove them in `ComponentWillUnmount`. I tried giving ref to the HOC (where it mounts the WrapperComponent) but it gave me an error that `node.addEventListener` is not a function because it is giving me a component's instance but not a DOM node of this HOC. How do I solve this problem using `refs`?

This is how my HOC looks like:

```
export default function Connector() {
    return function wrap(WrappedComponent) {
        class MyComponent extends PureComponent {
            componentDidMount(){
                //find node here and attach event listener
            }
            componentWillUnmount(){
                //remove event listener
            }
            ....
            render() {
               <WrappedComponent 
                   {...this.props}
               />
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I don't want to use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a ref to the WrappedComponent and then find the DOM instance

```
export default function Connector() {
    return function wrap(WrappedComponent) {
        class MyComponent extends PureComponent {
            componentDidMount(){
                //find node here and attach event listener
                this.node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.componentRef);

            }
            componentWillUnmount(){
                //remove event listener
            }

            ....
            render() {
               <WrappedComponent 
                   {...this.props}
                   ref={(ref) => this.componentRef = ref}
               />
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another way is to pass on a prop innerRef to the WrappedComponent and leave it to the wrappedComponent to pass the ref to the DOM node

```
   <WrappedComponent 
        {...this.props}
        innerRef={(ref) => this.componentRef = ref}
   />
```

And then in WrappedComponent

```
 render() {
     return (
        <div ref={this.props.innerRef}>{/* */}</div>
     )
  }
```

Comment: This answer is correct but I don't want to use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode`

Comment: In such a case, you need to pass a prop innerRef to the WrappedComponent and then depend on the WrappedComponent to pass it on to the DOM node as a ref

Comment: But that would be depending on the inner components that they would take the ref and put that on a DOM element. Will that be a good design?

Comment: @AjayGaur exactly my point, these are the two options available and hence I preferred the initial solution to use ReactDOM.findDOMNode because depending on the user Component to provide some data isn't a good model. Also its advisable to avoid findDOMNode as much as possible but not completely

Comment: Thanks, that helped. We can use invariant if we're doing the 2nd way.